# modify dag runs when triggered

Tags: airflow

I was curious if there's a way to customise the dag runs.
So I'm currently checking for updates for another table which gets updated manually by someone and once that's been updated, I would run my dag for the month.

At the moment I have created a branch operator that compares the dates of the 2 tables but is there a way to run the dag (compare the two dates) and run it everyday until there is a change and not run for the remaining of the month?

For example,

Table A (that is updated manually) has YYYYMM as 202209 and Table B also has YYYYMM as 202209.

Atm, my branch operator compares the two YYYYMM and would point to a dummy operator end when it's the same. However, when Table A has been updated to 202210, there's a difference in the two YYYYMM hence another task would run and overwrite Table B.
It all works but this would run the dag everyday even though the table A only gets updated once a month at a random point of time within the month. So is there way to trigger the dag to stop for the remaining days of the month after the task has been triggered?

Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you would be using data stored on S3 there would be easy solution starting from the version 2.4 - the [Data-aware scheduling](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/datasets.html).
But probably you're not so there is another option.

A dag in Airflow is Dag object that is assigned to global scope. This allows for dynamic creation of dags. This implies each file is loaded on certain [interval](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/scheduler.html#:%7E:text=CPU%20usage%20is%20most%20important%20for%20FileProcessors%20%2D%20those%20are%20the%20processes%20that%20parse%20and%20execute%20Python%20DAG%20files.%20Since%20Schedulers%20triggers%20such%20parsing%20continuously%2C%20when%20you%20have%20a%20lot%20of%20DAGs%2C%20the%20processing%20might%20take%20a%20lot%20of%20CPU.%20You%20can%20mitigate%20it%20by%20increasing%20the%20min_file_process_interval%2C). A very good description with examples is [here](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/dynamically-generating-dags)

Second thing you need to use is [Airflow Variables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/variable.html)

So the concept is as follows:

1. Create a variable in Airflow named `dag_run` that will hold the month when the dag has successfully run
2. Create a python file that has a function that creates a dag object based on input parameters.
3. In the same file use conditional statements that will set the 'schedule' param differently depending if the dag has run for current month
4. In your dag in the branch that executes when data has changed set the variable `dag_run` to the current months value like so: `Variable.set(key='dag_run', value=datetime.now().month)`

step 1:
[image: airflow variable]

python code:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models import Variable

#function that creates dag based on input
def create_dag(dag_id,
               schedule,
               default_args):

    def hello_world_py(*args):
        print('Hello World')
        print('This is DAG: {}'.format(str(dag_id)))

    dag = DAG(dag_id,
              schedule_interval=schedule,
              default_args=default_args)

    with dag:
        t1 = PythonOperator(
            task_id='hello_world',
            python_callable=hello_world_py)

    return dag

#run some checks
current_month = datetime.now().month
dag_run_month = int(Variable.get('run_month'))
if current_month == dag_run_month:
    # keep the schedule off
    schedule = None
    dag_id = "Database_insync"
elif current_month != dag_run_month:
    # keep the schedule on
    schedule = "30 * * * *"
    dag_id = "Database_notsynced"

#watch out for start_date if you leave 
#it in the past airflow will execute past missing schedules
default_args = {'owner': 'airflow',
            'start_date': datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
                }

globals()[dag_id] = create_dag(dag_id,
                              schedule,
                                  default_args)
```